# Uniform convergence in closed disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (z - a)^k$ be a power series with radius of convergence $R$. Then for all $r$ in $(0,R)$, the series is uniformly convergent in the closed disc $\bar{N}(a,r)$.

I'm in the process of teaching myself Complex Analysis, so any help would be great (but try not to make the hint too big). Thanks.

Comment: You may want to consider the meaning of $\limsup_k a_k$. In particular, what do you get when $\frac{1}{\limsup_k a_k} > r$? You may then prove the result by considering a geometric series.

Comment: Does having a power series converge uniformly on a closed disc or open disk imply globally the series converges uniformly over the entire region or is the condition just local ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments: $R_1=|z_1-z_0|$ and $z$ in the open disk $|z-z_0|<R_1$.

Proof: Suppose that the series, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(z_1-z_0)^n, z_1 \neq z_0 \ \ \ \ (converges)$.

Then the terms $a_n(z_1-z_0)^n$ are bounded, that is: $|a_n(z_1-z_0)^n|\leq M$, $(n=0,1,2,..)$.

If $|z_1-z_0|<R_1$ and if we write, $$\epsilon=\frac{|z-z_0|}{|z_1-z_0|},$$

We can see that, $|a_n(z-z_0)^n|=|a_n(z_1-z_0)^n|(\frac{|z-z_0|}{|z_1-z_0|})^n\leq M\epsilon^n$, $(n=0,1,2,..)$.

Now the series, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} M\epsilon^n$ is a geometric series, which converges since $\epsilon<1$. Hence, by comparison test for series, $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n(z-z_0)^n|$$

Converges in the open disk $|z-z_0|<R_1$.